# Javascript position variable doesn't update properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, position, updating

I've been sitting here for the past 3 hours thinking of and googling about a way to get a rectangle (div element) moving back and forth (with javascript) on the press of a button. It was moving, but then I was trying to monitor a collision and it didn't work. It said total trash, so I slimmed the code down to this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    var SQposition = $("#SQbody").position();
    var SQleft = SQposition.left;
    var SQtop = SQposition.top;
    //Go left D or left arrow key
    if(e.keyCode == 68 || e.keyCode == 39) {
        console.log("Fired");
        $("#SQbody").css({
            "left": (SQleft + 10) + "px",
        });
    }
});
```

No matter where I monitor the variable `SQleft`, it always fires a 0 then obviously a ten and so on. The strange thing about is, that using something like `console.log("Fired");` starts with 1 then 2 and so on.
What am I doing wrong?
**Update:** by "Go left" I mean "Go right", it was 3am when I coded that xD
**Solution:** I solved it myself by putting a `+=` into the brackets
and returning the variable SQleft after logging it to the console.
The working code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    var SQposition = $("#SQbody").position();
    var SQleft = SQposition.left;
    var SQtop = SQposition.top;
    if(e.keyCode == 68 || e.keyCode == 39) {
        $("#SQbody").css({
            "left": (SQleft += 10) + "px",
        });
        console.log("Fired " + SQleft);
        return SQleft;
    }
});
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? It's going up only. You would have to minus the 10 to go left. `console` logs occur in numerical order.

Comment: This
`#SQbody {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                background-color: #FFD94D;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 100px;
                left: 0px;
                -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
            }`
is the only CSS element I'm having. The scripts are Jquery and plain Javascript and are included at the end of the body tag. And `SQbody` is the only element on the page. I did an more advanced version earlier on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BooRvg) You control it with W, A and D.

Comment: @PHPglue it doesn't matter where I put the `console.log();` or `.text();` SQleft is always saying the last value. In the Codepen thing I've made you can see it if you look at the `#SQbody` in the Dev Tools. You move it by one, the console says 100, but the actual value is 115. And of course it gets really messy if you move it in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/p2227/pen/GppvOE

is it misses `position: absolute;`??

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's not influenced by any other object because it's on `position: fixed;` Look at my comment under my question for more detail